# Remove Laravel Lumen Public path Ubuntu Cloud Server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, apache2, lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm trying to remove public path on lumen 5.2 on a ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I already allow **mod_rewrite** on my apache

also added this to my apache2.conf to allow Overrides

```
<Directory /var/www/html/lumen>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm getting the error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

But if I added the `public` path to url it works. Any one having this trouble?

I'm trying to make the url from
`http://www.example.com/public` to `http://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/lumen>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/html/lumen/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Because your document root is `public` directory. And remove that `public/` from `.htaccess`

Comment: Still having the same problem and also when I remove `public/` for my .htaccess its showing my directory list and not to my public folder

Comment: Do You restored default `.htaccess` https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/public/.htaccess ?

Comment: I didn't edit the .htaccess from `public` folder instead I make a new one on my root directory

Comment: Try to remove that new `.htaccess`. Also make sure your `DocumentRoot` pointing to `public` directory.

Comment: I already did but same thing happens just like my first comment

Comment: Strange, can You attach all virtual host configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

Restore your original `.htaccess` and never edit it.

Edit your Apache config file, you should have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/lumen/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/lumen/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache.